# Why does SQL display an & as &amp;?

Tags: sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [help with FOR XML PATH('') escaping “special” characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051362/help-with-for-xml-path-escaping-special-characters)

I need some assistance, my query is below:

```
STUFF(
    (
      SELECT ',' + CountDesc
      FROM Count INNER JOIN ProjectCount ON Count.Id =  ProjectCount.CountId 
      WHERE ProjectCount.ProjectId = Project.Id ORDER BY Count.CountDesc
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') as  [Country]
```

What happens is when i run this query and the Count table has an & in one of its fields, it displays the & as `&amp;`.

Is there anyway to not let this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer in that post!

Comment: You need to specify the TYPE directive as the following script.}

''FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')''

Answer (score 9):

It is happening because the strings being combined in the XML statement are using XML specific characters.  In addition to &, the also affects < and >, and probably other characters.

I usually fix this be doing a replace after the call:

```
select @str = replace(@str, '&amp;', '&')
```

And nesting the replaces for additional characters.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax) of the XML spec, `&` must be escaped except for in a few special cases (e.g. within a comment or CDATA section). If the `&` wasn't displayed as `&amp;`, the XML would be invalid.