# ORDER BY suddenly conflicting with VARCHAR concatenation in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, concatenation

I have code in Sql Server 2008 which concatenates some strings from a query into a variable using the tried-and-true `SELECT @VAR = @VAR + FIELD FROM TABLE ORDER BY OTHERFIELD` syntax.

This is my exact SQL:

```
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
    ISNULL(FORMULA, 
    CASE WHEN USEMAP = 1 THEN 
        'dbo.getFieldTranslation('+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROWID)+', [' + ISNULL(ENCOMPASSFIELD,'') + '])' 
    ELSE 
        '[' + ISNULL(ENCOMPASSFIELD,'') + ']' END
    ) + 
    ' AS "' + FILECOLNAME + '",' + @CRLF  
FROM dbo.EXPORTMAP_EX 
WHERE WAREHOUSEID = @WHSID 
ORDER BY ORDERIDX
```

This was working beautifully and perfectly. Then suddenly today, it stopped working. It was only concatenating on the last row's values. In debugging, I found out that if I take out the `ORDER BY` clause, then all the fields come back, but sorted strictly alphabetically by the string value of the fields.

This SQL however is being used to generate a view for an export. The export file must have its fields in the proper order, hence the ORDER BY clause. Why is the ORDER BY suddenly serving to ***filter*** my results?

I cannot use the XML/STUFF route because some of the data does have < and > signs in it.
I'd rather not have to go back to using an old WHILE loop, but I may have to.

Comment: Well this pattern is not so "tried-and-true", then... That's because you are relying on undocumented behavior.

Comment: This is actually known to be 'tried and failed'.

Comment: What happens if you do the `order by` in a sub-query and concatenate the results of this query?

Comment: ORDER BY the sub-query it returns all rows alpha-sorted again. I'm surprised by the comments. I thought this was pretty much the "standard" way of doing row-value concatenation in SQL server. Interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments you are relying on undocumented behaviour.

Microsoft say "[The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us)". If the compute scalar moves to the wrong place in the plan then it just stops working.

The work around you are using of defining the ordering expression in a sub-query and concatenating the results of this query <strike>I *believe* is safe</strike> . From [Ordering guarantees in SQL Server...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx)

> For backwards compatibility reasons, SQL Server provides support for
>   assignments of type SELECT @p = @p + 1 ... ORDER BY at the top-most
>   scope.

That posting was written in 2005 though so I'm not sure if the guarantee still holds (Edit: After [reviewing Connect Items on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/73226) I'm sure that it doesn't)

BTW: You say

> I cannot use the XML/STUFF route because some of the data does have <
>   and > signs in it. I'd rather not have to go back to using an old
>   WHILE loop, but I may have to.

This is not the case but it needs a slightly more complicated `XML PATH` query than you were probably using [see the answer here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052353/73226).

Comment: Thanks for that link to the support.microsoft article. This is good to know.