# T-SQL trying to determine the largest string from a set of concatenated strings in a database

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have two tables.  One has an Order number, and details about the order:

```
CREATE TABLE #Order ( OrderID int )
```

and the second contains comments about the order:

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderComments ( OrderID int
                              Comment VarChar(500) )
Order ID      Comments
~~~~~~~~      ~~~~~~~~
1             Loved this item!
1             Could use some work
1             I've had better
2             Try the veal
```

I'm tasked with determining the maximum length of the output, then returning output like the following:

```
Order ID      Comments                                                  Length
~~~~~~~~      ~~~~~~~~                                                  ~~~~~~
1             Loved this item! | Could use some work | I've had better  56
2             Try the veal                                              12
```

So, in this example, if this is all of the data, I'm looking for "56").

The main purpose is to determine the maximum length of all comments when appended together, including the `|` delimiter.  This will be used when constructing the table this output will be put into, to determine if we can get the data within [the 8,060 size limit for a row](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx) or if we need to use varchar(max) or text to hold the data.

I have tried a couple of subqueries that can generate this output to variables, but I haven't found one yet that could generate the above output.  If I could get that, then I could just do a `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY 3 DESC` to get the number I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what the length of the longest string will be if you trim and concatenate all the (not null) comments belonging to an OrderId with a delimiter of length three you can use

```
SELECT TOP(1) SUM(LEN(Comment)) + 3* (COUNT(Comment) - 1) AS Length
FROM OrderComments
GROUP BY OrderId
ORDER BY Length DESC
```

To actually do the concatenation you can use `XML PATH` as demonstrated in many other answers on this site.

```
WITH O AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT OrderID
FROM #Order
)
SELECT O.OrderID,
       LEFT(y.Comments, LEN(y.Comments) - 1) AS Comments
FROM   O
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT ltrim(rtrim(Comment)) + ' | '
                    FROM   #OrderComments oc
                    WHERE  oc.OrderID = O.OrderID
                    AND Comment  IS NOT NULL
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) x (Comments)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT x.Comments.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) y(Comments)
```

Comment: The crazy thing is that I hit upon this answer within minutes of posting the question.  Now, any idea how to generate the output above, with the values concatenated together?

Comment: I had a look at the `XML PATH`, but also read that it shouldn't be used if `&` and `<` could be present in the text, which this could easily contain those.

Comment: @Dan it can be used but you need to use it a bit differently than the more common code found. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1052353/73226

Comment: Is there a variation of `CONCAT` that is usable on versions of SQL Server older than 2014?

Comment: `CONCAT` doesn't concatenate across rows anyway. I've edited the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/451441/73226) to include a version that works with those characters and added a version to this answer.

Comment: I looked at the link you provided, and brought it into a new query window so I could start dissecting it, but it complains with `Invalid object name 'Numbers'`.  The OP of that thread didn't mention what ver of SQL he was working with, but I'm guessing it's newer than 2008?

Comment: @Dan - You would need to change the table names to select from your tables.

Comment: Change that to a `SELECT DISTINCT O.OrderID` and it's a perfect fit!  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan - Ah OK, assumed that would be the PK of Orders.

Comment: Doh! of course.  Here I thought it was some new feature of a newer SQL Server... (facepalm)

Comment: @Dan - Lots of people have such a table as standard for reasons here [Why are numbers tables “invaluable”?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/3690)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66523/discussion-between-dan-and-martin-smith).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is STUFF function and XML PATH

Check out this sql fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65cc6/5