# Add attribute with colon to xml node with FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to modify a stored proc to contain the following:

```
SET @XML = (    
    SELECT Category.Title,
        (       
            SELECT 'true' AS [@json:Array], Book.Name, Book.Value
            FROM @Book Book
            WHERE Category.CategoryID = Book.CategoryID
            FOR XML PATH('Values'), ROOT('Book'), TYPE
        ) 
    FROM @Category Category
    FOR XML PATH('Category'), ROOT('Response')
)
```

The "SELECT 'true' AS [@json:Array]" is there to force the xml to add "json:Array='true' to the values node so that even if there's only one child element it will be contained in an array.  But, the @json:Array throws an error: "XML name space prefix 'json' declaration is missing for FOR XML column name '@json:Array'."

I've looked at links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051362/help-with-for-xml-path-escaping-special-characters) but they all seem to deal with adding attributes that don't include a colon.  I've also tried adding "WITH NAMESPACES..." but couldn't get the syntax right.

Can someone tell me how to modify the SQL to have this work?

Comment: Could you post sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ (more info: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @Shnugo, you're absolutely right and I do apologise for the inattentiveness.  And thank you for the vote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do it like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('xmlns:json' AS json)
SELECT @XML=
(
    SELECT 'YourTitle',
        (       
            SELECT 'true' AS [@json:Array], 'BookName', 'BookValue'
            FOR XML PATH('Values'), ROOT('Book'), TYPE
        ) 
    FOR XML PATH('Category'), ROOT('Response')
) 
SELECT @xml
```

... you'll get the attribut. But the price is a repeated namespace in all of your root nodes (in nested too).

This might be a trick, but you'll have to declare your namespace in the top element:

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
SELECT @XML=
(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(
    (
    SELECT 'YourTitle',
        (       
            SELECT 'true' AS [@jsonArray], 'BookName', 'BookValue'
            FOR XML PATH('Values'), ROOT('Book'), TYPE
        ) 
    FOR XML PATH('Category'), ROOT('Response')
    ),'jsonArray','json:Array'),'<Response','<Response xmlns:json="urnJson"')
); 

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo - your suggestion got me to my solution.  Here's what worked for me:
`
 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json' AS json)
   SELECT @XML = ( 
    SELECT 'true' AS '@json:Array', Category.Title,
     (    
      SELECT 
       'true' AS '@json:Array',
       Book.Name, 
       Book.Value
      FROM @Book Book
      WHERE Category.CategoryID = Book.CategoryID
      FOR XML PATH('Values'), ROOT('Book'), TYPE
     ) 
    FROM @Category Category
    FOR XML PATH('Category'), ROOT('Response')
   )
`
 The james.newtonking.com namespace seemed to be required.