# xml display &amp; instead of & sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, special-characters, for-xml-path

I have a table from which i am generating XML using below code

```
Select CASE WHEN changed=0 THEN 'False' WHEN changed=1 THEN 'True' ELSE Null END As "@changed",
            Name as 'Name', 
            Integer AS 'Value/Integer',
            Decimal AS 'Value/Decimal',
            Dimensions AS 'Value/Dimensions',
            Units AS 'Value/Units',
            Percentage AS 'Value/Percentage',
            code AS 'Value/code',
            text AS 'Value/text',
            CASE WHEN boolean=0 THEN 'False' WHEN boolean=1 THEN 'True' ELSE Null END AS 'Value/boolean'
            from [abc].[xyz_detail_table](nolock) CD where code_ids='268973407' FOR XML PATH('Detail'), TYPE
```

Here text column has value as

> Horse & Horse

but in the output xml it is coming as

```
> Horse &amp; Horse
```

I have followed this below question but in my case TYPE is already mentioned. Can you please guide me how to resolve this issue

[FOR XML PATH(''): Escaping "special" characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051362/for-xml-path-escaping-special-characters)

Table DML used for column TEXT:
Text(varchar(254),null)

Comment: Table definition and sample data would go a long way to making this question better.

Comment: Probably worth reading this also as I see that nasty nolock hint in there. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: That's correct. *Valid* XML can't contain an ampersand (`&`) in the text value, as it's a reserved character. When you *consume* that value (in whatever it is you use) the parser will know to *display* that value as `&`. For example `SELECT CONVERT(xml,'<t>Horse &amp; Horse</t>').value('(t/text())[1]','varchar(30)')` returns `'Horse & Horse'`

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: @Larnu This did not worked when it gets converted to XML. I used SELECT CONVERT(xml,'<t>Horse &amp; Horse</t>').value('(t/text())[1]','varchar(30)') as result_o FOR XML PATH('Detail'), TYPE . Output has &amp; in it.

Comment: You are converting it *back* to XML in that SQL, @insanity; of course it'll go back to `&amp;`...

Comment: This is the requirement for me. In the xml it should display proper & not &amp;

Comment: As I stated, that is invalid XML. If you need to do that, you'll need to `CONVERT` the `xml` to a different data type (likely an `(n)varchar`) and then use nested replaces for any and *all* escape sequences that might appear in your data. You will then have to treat the value in your entire process as a string value, *not* an `xml` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I state in the comments, the ampersand (`&`) is a reserved character in XML, as such when you put a value, such as `'Horse & Horse'` into an XML node's text value, the ampersand is escaped (to `&amp;`).

When parsing said value, your parsing application will read that escape sequence and display it correctly. Take the following:

```sql
SELECT t.x,
       t.x.value('(t/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS v
FROM  (SELECT *
       FROM (VALUES ('Horse & Horse'))V(t)
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) t(x);
```

This returns the `xml` value `<t>Horse &amp; Horse</t>` and the `varchar` value `'Horse & Horse'`; when SQL Server consumed the node's value it changed the `&amp;` to `&`.

If you "must" *not* have `&amp;` then you can't treat your value as `xml`. You will need to `CONVERT` the value to a string based data type, and then `REPLACE` all the escape sequences you need to:

```sql
SELECT t.x,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(MAX),t.x),'&amp;','&'),'&gt;','>'),'&lt;','<')
FROM  (SELECT *
       FROM (VALUES ('Horse & Horse'))V(t)
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) t(x)
```

Of course, if you try to `CONVERT` that value (`'<t>Horse & Horse</t>'`) back to `xml`, you'll get an error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 11, illegal name character

So once you malform the XML, you will have to leave it as a string based data type, and you won't be able to consume it using SQL Server's XQuery tools.